# Print html document from .NET

Tags: html, .net, printing

I am currently trying to print a formatted HTML document from C# and also set the printer settings for this process (landscape, margins, etc.).

I've checked for possible solutions online, but all of them seem kind of old, and none of those really worked.

For example the latest try was using System.Diagnostics.Process and setting up the StartInfo configuration for the printer and html file document.

This code I have used:

```
Process process = new Process();
printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + + "\\\\printerAddress\\PrinterName" + "\"";
process.StartInfo.FileName = htmlPagePath;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "printto"; 
//process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(htmlPagePath); 
process.Start();

process.WaitForInputIdle();
process.Kill();
```

Can you please tell us what could be the best solution in this case? Or what are we doing wrong in the code above?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried adjusting the css settings of your file html file. i normally adjust that to make it fit my pages works great for me. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: yes, I have tried, but IE 11 doesn't support most of the page settings. The main issue is about printing the HTML from the server side on a remote printer, thing that i can't figure out yet. Thank you for the response. :)